# There is any drawback in using reflection to copy objects?

Tags: .net, reflection, clr

I'm using reflection to copy data between objects who implement the same interface, everything seems to work fine, but before deploying to production I wanted to ask: is there any reason why I should avoid doing this?

My previous implementation with hard-coded properties was not able to detect additions to the interface nor was able to avoid me or my team to mistakenly copy a property to another of the same type.

Also, I'm caching on a static dictionary the properties by type, does this have any advantage or i'm just doubling the CLR dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems with using Reflection in the manner described:

1. It will generally be slower than directly-written code, and sometimes severely slower.
2. It presupposes that all information to be copied will be accessible the same way.

While it may sometimes be possible to use Reflection to produce proxy objects for classes whose functionality would map nicely to an interface, but which cannot be modified to actually implement it, I would suggest that if you control the classes and the interfaces, you should include within interfaces all the functionality necessary to copy objects so as to avoid the need to use Reflection even if new features are added (e.g. define methods to construct new objects with data copied from old ones--including data which the caller might not know about).

Comment: Which part is slower? The one where I get the properties of the interface (it get executed once) or the one where i do setvalue(getvalue()) ? I think I'll write some benchmarks...

Comment: It's possible to use Reflection to generate reasonably-efficient code.  It won't be as fast as direct dispatch, but can work decently.  The bigger issue, which I should perhaps describe in more detail, is the second.  There are times when it's necessary for an interface contract to specify "Any legitimate implementation of this interface must have a static method called X with signature Y", and for a helper method of such an interface to use Reflection to call such a method.  The existence of such methods would normally be an "implementation detail" rather than part of an interface contract...

Comment: ...but it's sometimes helpful to have a generic method which accepts a type `T` constrained to e.g. `IConstructableFrom<T,String>` so code with a `String` can convert it to a `T` from it.  In general, though, interfaces contracts should avoid specifying how things should work with Reflection.  It's icky semantically, even when performance would be acceptable.

Comment: as soon as i have a little time (after the holidays) i'll try to show how i'm using this and maybe i'll accept your answer, because for now it's the more reasonable.

Comment: I did the tests, and the maths, and IT IS slower, the fact is even if it is ten times slower, or 100 times slower, it is actually so fast using this is mostly ok for most of the cases, i got a medium times of 80Ticks agaist a medium time of 10 running the copies for 1000 times, and a medium of still 80 against 2 running the copies for 100000 times, this confuses me a bit but it is still ok to me i will use this instead of risking to miss some fields

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to your previous implementation is to use tools like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) so you don't have to write the mapping code yourself.

Comment: does `AutoMapper` also use `Reflecton` behind the scene?

Comment: It took something like 10 rows to write my own which I can control easily and I know how it works and I don't have to worry how I can distribute... So... No, doesn't look like a nice idea to me...